# Timeseries Anomaly Detection

Tags: python, math, time-series, anomaly-detection

I have daily data of multiple products (total sales count and amount).

Manually we can see the anomaly in the count or amount like if there is a dip or hike in data by plotting them.

But now we have lots of products and can not track them manually. So now I am looking for a solution that can detect anomalies in each product.

Like in the below picture, the blue line shows the daily count of one product for the last 30 days.

I also tried to calculate the Exponentially weighted Average (orange line and added margin in gray line).

[image: Blue line shows the daily trend of data]

Then I get the data for the same product for the same weekdays. like if data is of if will get the data of Mondays.

then took the same exponentially weighted averages.

[image: Weekday's stats of product]

Then I created the 3rd graph by adding the weightages of both graphs. like took 30% from first value and 70% from the second.

[image: combined graphs]

But still, I am not sure if it will work fine.

Or if there are better ways to detect anomalies.

I hope if I was able to describe the actual problem.

Please try to be kind as I am very new to this and don't have much knowledge. Some useful articles will also be helpful thanks.

Comment: This is not really a program-related question - wouldn't [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) be the more appropriate forum for this kind of algorithmic problem?

Comment: You need to have a definition of what you consider to be "anomalous" and "normal" data.